# retrieving data from cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I'm working on smart parking data stored in Cassandra database and i'm trying to get the last status of each device.
I'm working on self-made dataset.
here's the description of the table. 
[table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8axz.png)

[select * from parking.meters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TScum.png)

need help please !

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for, not clear what is not working...

Answer (score 1):

> trying to get the last status of each device

In Cassandra, you need to design your tables according to your query patterns.  Building a table, filling it with data, and then trying to fulfill a query requirement is a very **backward** approach.  The point, is that if you really need to satisfy that query, then your table should have been designed to *serve* that query **from the beginning**.

That being said, there may still be a way to make this work.  You haven't mentioned which version of Cassandra you are using, but if you are on 3.6+, you can use the PER PARTITION LIMIT clause on your SELECT.

If I build your table structure and INSERT some of your rows:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM meters ;

 parking_id | device_id | date                 | status
------------+-----------+----------------------+--------
          1 |        20 | 2017-01-12T12:14:58Z |  False
          1 |        20 | 2017-01-10T09:11:51Z |   True
          1 |        20 | 2017-01-01T13:51:50Z |  False
          1 |         7 | 2017-01-13T01:20:02Z |  False
          1 |         7 | 2016-12-02T16:50:04Z |   True
          1 |         7 | 2016-11-24T23:38:31Z |  False
          1 |        19 | 2016-12-14T11:36:26Z |   True
          1 |        19 | 2016-11-22T15:15:23Z |  False

(8 rows)
```

And I consider your PRIMARY KEY and CLUSTERING ORDER definitions:

```
  PRIMARY KEY ((parking_id, device_id), date, status)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC, status ASC);
```

You are at least clustering by date (which should be an actual date type, not a text), so that will order your rows in a way that helps you here:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM meters PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;

 parking_id | device_id | date                 | status
------------+-----------+----------------------+--------
          1 |        20 | 2017-01-12T12:14:58Z |  False
          1 |         7 | 2017-01-13T01:20:02Z |  False
          1 |        19 | 2016-12-14T11:36:26Z |   True

(3 rows)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i'm working with cassandra 3.0.9.